# c# - open excel workbook with different working directory

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to open an Excel workbook from the temp directory, but specify an alternative working directory so that when the user goes to save the workbook the default save location is not the temp folder.

Here's what I am trying

```
Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", string.Format("\"{0}\" /p \"{1}\"", workbookPath, desktopPath);
```

Excel opens the workbook, but the /p switch path is ignored.  When I go to save the workbook, the default save location is the temp directory (where the file was opened from)

If I simply...

```
Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", string.Format("/p {0}", desktopPath));
```

... a blank excel workbook is opened (as expected) and the working directory is correctly set to the desktop.  I've played with several different paths and the switch definitely works when I don't try to also open a workbook.

I'm starting to think that what I am trying to do is not possible, as I can't even get what I want to work by using a plain old command prompt.  I get the same results as what I have described above.

Have I messed something up, or is there another way to do what I am trying to do?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention.. using Office 2010 in a Windows 7/8.1 environment

Comment: Use an absolute path for the saving rather than a relative.

Comment: @Takarii thanks for the tip - I have tried this and it still doesn't seem to work.  Here's what I am doing via command prompt (also not working): c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14>excel.exe "C:\users\myuser\appdata\local\temp\foo.xlsx" /p "C:\users\myuser\desktop"